Assembling with gcc gives error operand type mismatch for `cmp' for some integers, not others
This is a weird one. I'm using gcc to assemble a program and I want to know if the value in register rsi fits in 32 bits, so I use this instruction:
cmpq $0xffffffff, %rsi

I get back an error that there's an operand mismatch. I've been playing around with it and if I delete one or more of the letters f, so for instance $0xfffffff, the error goes away. If there are eight to fifteen letters f, it gives the operand mismatch error. However, at sixteen (the maximum 64-bit number), the error goes away again. Putting a leading 0 after the x doesn't seem to help.
I suspect this is a bug with gcc, but I don't know how something so obvious as this could go unnoticed. Am I making a mistake in how I'm typing out hexadecimal numbers?

It is not a bug and even if it were it would be in the assembler not the compiler. The instruction only stores 32 bits of the immediate which is sign extended to 64 bits. To quote the manual: "REX.W + 81 /7 id CMP r/m64, imm32 Compare imm32 sign-extended to 64-bits with r/m64." Operands where the top 32 bits don't match bit #31 are not encodable. Admittedly the error message could be a little better.

I don't think this can be done in a single instruction.  The fastest way would probably to do a 32 bit move to a new register and then do a 64 bit comparison if old and new are identical.  It's likely that the move is executed as a rename, which is free at runtime.

To check if an unsigned value fits in 32bits, you can right-shift it by 32 and check if the result is zero -- but this destroys the register content of course. So copying with a 32bit move and doing a 64bit compare as suggested by @fuz will likely be more practical in most situations.

Side note, make sure you know whether you want signed or unsigned.

You guys are absolutely right. I assumed the two operands for a compare instruction had to match. I'll just have to use the copy trick mentioned above, shift the bits right, or just default to 64-bit division like I was originally doing as the few saved clock cycles don't appear to be worth the extra instructions. Thanks.
